# How to import CSV with Japanese text to PostgreSQL table?

Tags: postgresql, character-encoding

I'm beginner in SQL. I would like to import a CSV file with Japanese text to a PostgreSQL table. I created a table and tried importing the CSV but this error exit:

```
ERROR:  invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0x8c
CONTEXT:  COPY tTokyoDir, line 1

********** Error **********

ERROR: invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0x8c
SQL state: 22021
Context: COPY tTokyoDir, line 1
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Can you also post your import command?

Comment: It has been a long time since I did anything with SQL, but it sounds like your table is UTF-8 encoded while your data is EUC-JP or perhaps Shift-JIS. Re-save your file as UTF-8 encoded rather than your local encoding, whatever that may be.

Comment: As @ChronoKitsune said, unless the data is supposed to be UTF-8, you'll need to convert it to UTF-8 from its current code set (maybe using `iconv`) before importing it. Or you will have to set up the database so that it expects the correct Japanese code set (but then it won't be able to store text from other languages such as Hebrew, Arabic or Russian that use letters not found in Japanese). If the data is supposed to be UTF-8, then there's a bug in the code generating the 'UTF-8' data; you can't have a byte 0x8C (a continuation byte) as the first byte of a character, but that's what you have.

Answer (score 1):

You need to identify the encoding of the CSV file, since it's not `utf-8`.

See [How to auto detect text file encoding?](https://superuser.com/questions/301552/how-to-auto-detect-text-file-encoding) if you need help with that.

As said in the comments, `EUC-JP` and `Shift-JIS` are plausible encodings for japanese, both are supported by postgres.

Then instruct the server to expect that encoding for the duration of the import.

For example:

```
SET client_encoding TO 'EUC-JP';
COPY table_name FROM 'file.csv' CSV;
SET client_encoding TO default;
```

This method converts the data on the fly, it's the simplest way and works for any PostgreSQL version.

If you use 9.1 or a more recent version, `COPY` has an `ENCODING` argument that makes it a one-liner:

```
COPY table_name FROM 'file.csv' CSV ENCODING 'EUC-JP';
```